# Error - Try use a background .gif image in Turtle

Tags: python, python-3.8, python-turtle

I'm trying run this code, but this error still persist:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/Rafae/PycharmProjects/cutucos_race/main.py", line 8, in 
screen.bgpic("bgimage.gif")
File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\turtle.py", line 1482, in bgpic
self._bgpics[picname] = self.*image(picname)
File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\turtle.py", line 478, in *image
return TK.PhotoImage(file=filename, master=self.cv)
File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\tkinter_*init**.py", line 4064, in **init**
Image.**init**(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)
File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\tkinter_*init**.py", line 4009, in **init**
self.tk.call(('image', 'create', imgtype, name,) + options)
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't recognize data in image file "bgimage.gif"

The code with I trying running is:

```
import turtle
import random

bg_image = "bgimage.gif"
image = "scoz_kart.gif"

screen = turtle.Screen()
screen.bgpic("bgimage.gif")

is_race_on = False

screen.register_shape(image)
user_bet = " "
screen.setup(width=900, height=600)
y_positions = [-200, -100, 0, 100, 200]
all_turtles = []

for turtle_index in range(0, 5):
    new_turtle = turtle.Turtle(shape=image)[enter image description here][1]
    new_turtle.penup()
    new_turtle.goto(x=-430, y=y_positions[turtle_index])
    all_turtles.append(new_turtle)

if user_bet:
    is_race_on = True

while is_race_on:

    for turtle in all_turtles:
        if turtle.xcor() > 400:
            winning_color = turtle.pencolor()
            is_race_on = False
        random_distance = random.randint(0, 10)
        turtle.forward(random_distance)



screen.mainloop()
```

Comment: What steps have you taken to verify that `bgimage.gif` is actually a valid GIF file?

Comment: In fact, i converted a .JPEG file saving as .GIF file.

Comment: Substitute an existing GIF file that *you* didn't convert to see if that works better.  If so, revisit your JPG -> GIF conversion process.